# Shell redirect output to variable and console output at same time

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How to redirect command output to variable and console same time.

Example:

```
 var=`ls -l`
```

I want to print output in console at the same time and not later "echo $var"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var=$(ls -l | tee /dev/stderr)
```

Note that this is assumed to just be an example -- [you should **never** use `ls` in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), except where the output will only be consumed by human readers.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [tee](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) command.

> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>    Copy standard input to each FILE, and also to standard output.
> ```